# LED uniform spread of light

Tags: experimental-physics, light-emitting-diodes

I am using an LED in my project. I need to provide uniform intensity or uniform spread of light using this LED in a particular area(Small region). Please tell some techniques for this. I have read about the use of plain glass with some chemical coating and place in front of the LED. Anybody knows about these? Please help me to find an appropriate technique.

Comment: What is a "Small region"?  How uniform does it have to be?  You could put a lens in front of the LED and use just a small part of the diverging beam.

Comment: @ garyp. Which kind of lens can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Small region means the dimensions are 5cm x 5cm x 3cm. And led is placed 2.7cm away from my sample at the height of 1.5cm. Currently LED is not providing uniform light.

Comment: It's unlikely that you can easily get uniform illumination with an LED placed so close to such a volume.   You will need either an array of LEDs, perhaps 4x4, and then depending on how uniform you need it to be you might need something like ground glass to diffuse the light.  You might be able to get the illumination to be uniform enough by placing the LED about a meter away and diverging the light with a long focal length lens.   It's difficult to give you a solution that will work without knowing your constraints and the degree of uniformity you need.